# what is best way to sort lines in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'm looking for the best way to sort lines of RichTextBox, I'm using this at moment:

```
public void SortLines(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextPointer pStart = TextInput.Document.ContentStart;
    TextPointer pEnd = TextInput.Document.ContentEnd;
    TextRange text = new TextRange(pStart, pEnd);

    string[] lines = text.Text.Split('\n');
    Array.Sort(lines);
    text.Text = String.Join(String.Empty, lines);
}
```

1. Is there an best way to do this?
2. When I call it, the cursor is placed into first RichTextBox line, how do I to put it where it was before?
   I tried to set pStart/pEnd and CaretPositiom, but the properties are read only.

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you sorting by (first letter, number of letters, or anything)?  do you want the cursor to be placed in the same relative spot (i.e. if you have lines A,B,C and cursor is at B, then you sort and the new order is C,A,B then should the cursor stay with B or stay at A)?

Answer (score 1):

An inelegant but practical solution; back and forth richtextbox to ListBox :
In the properties on your listBox you click 'sorted'> true

[c#]

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(RichTextBox1.Lines);
for (int x = 0; (x 
            <= (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)); x++) {
    RichTextBox1.AppendText((ListBox1.Items(x).ToString.Environment.NewLine));
}
```

[VB.NET]

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(RichTextBox1.Lines)
For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
RichTextBox1.AppendText(ListBox1.Items(x).ToString & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

As far is it comes to sorting this solution is not to different from you suggested one, but I find it more elegant + it handles cursor location & selection:

```
public void SortLines(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       rtb.HideSelection = false; //for showing selection
        /*Saving current selection*/
        string selectedText = rtb.SelectedText;
        /*Saving curr line*/
        int firstCharInLineIndex = rtb.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
        int currLineIndex = rtb.Text.Substring(0, firstCharInLineIndex).Count(c => c == '\n');
        string currLine = rtb.Lines[currLineIndex];
        int offset = rtb.SelectionStart -firstCharInLineIndex;


        /*Sorting*/
        string[] lines = rtb.Lines;
        Array.Sort(lines, delegate(string str1, string str2) { return str1.CompareTo(str2); });
        rtb.Lines = lines;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty((selectedText)))
        {
            /*restoring selection*/
            int newIndex = rtb.Text.IndexOf(selectedText);
            rtb.Select(newIndex, selectedText.Length);
        }
        else
        {   /*Restoring the cursor*/

            //location of the current line
            int lineIdx = Array.IndexOf(rtb.Lines, currLine);
            int textIndex = rtb.Text.IndexOf(currLine);
            int fullIndex = textIndex + offset;
            rtb.SelectionStart =  fullIndex;
            rtb.SelectionLength = 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why pass in a comparer to `Sort`?  It'll do just fine without it?  Also, how does this maintain the cursor position?

Comment: @servy this is just for allowing th flexibility to change the criteria for the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eric Paroissien for your simple solution!  The C# code had a couple of issues - Here's his solution with the fix

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear();
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(RichTextBox1.Lines);
RichTextBox1.Clear();
for (int x = 0; (x <= (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)); x++)
{
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(ListBox1.Items[x].ToString());
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox works like an array, we can use array.sort this way :

```
    Dim MyArray() As String
    MyArray = RichTextBox1.Lines
    Array.Sort(MyArray)
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    For Each item In MyArray
        RichTextBox1.Text &= item & Environment.NewLine
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep your position, you can first save the TextPointer :

```
var sel = Richtextbox.CaretPosition;
```

Then, after sorting your text :

```
Richtextbox.Selection.Select(sel,sel);
```

This is my solution for a WPF project.